# how to enable popup-menu to communicate with WM_MENUCOMMAND instead of WM_COMMAND?

Tags: winapi, menu

What I read is that the menu must have its MenuInfo.dwStyle flag set to MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS, what I did is:

```
MENUINFO MenuInfo;
memset(&MenuInfo,0, sizeof(MenuInfo));
MenuInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MenuInfo);
HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
GetMenuInfo(hPopupMenu, &MenuInfo);
MenuInfo.dwStyle |= MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS;
SetMenuInfo(hPopupMenu, &MenuInfo);
```

And next proceed with adding items:

```
InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, pos, MF_BYPOSITION, id , "do command");
```

Next track it:

```
TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_CENTERALIGN | TPM_RETURNCMD, cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
```

But it has no effect, it compiles without error but the clicking event is till send as `WM_COMMAND`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the fMask member of the `MENUINFO` structure to tell the system which fields you want to set/get.

E.g.

```
MenuInfo.fMask = MIM_STYLE;
GetMenuInfo(hPopupMenu, &MenuInfo);
MenuInfo.dwStyle |= MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS;
SetMenuInfo(hPopupMenu, &MenuInfo);
```

Also note that the docs say:

> MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS is a menu header style and has no effect when applied
>   to individual sub menus.

So it is possible that it won't work for you anyway with a popup menu.